# Windows Phone 8.1 Voice Commands App Activation

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to integrate some voice commands in my windows phone 8.1 app.
The first thing I want to do is to open my app by a voice command and navigate to a certain page.

According to MSDN article [Quickstart: Voice commands (XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn630430.aspx) I can use the override of `protected virtual void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)` method in App.xaml.cs to meet my requirements. But it does'nt work the way I though it would!

I have the method with the following structure:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.VoiceCommand)
    {
        var commandArgs = args as VoiceCommandActivatedEventArgs;
        if (commandArgs != null)
        {
            // ... some logic here
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I'm activating my app by saying "Open 'name of my app' [optional words]" the app opens but the Activated event never fires! The app opens and OnLaunched event fires. So I can't even enter the OnActivated method.

Does anyone know the problem? Why can't I enter OnActivated method using voice commands?

P.S. I tried it with a simulator as well as with a real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see this article, 
http://t.co/Q5hRxRPvwR
is in spanish, but you will understand.

After you install the app and run it, the xml should be installed, like said in documentation.

After ask to cortana "What can I say?" it will show all you can said, and the apps that supports cortana. Choose you app and you will see what you can say for your app, like

[image]
[image]

If you say what your app can listen, your app will be activated.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it one more time and realized that you should say the phrase which is integrated in your app, in this case OnActivated method is called. Otherwise, if I say just "Open + the name of my app" the method isn't called. I got it.